# XCode 6 Storyboard UI depiction does not translate to what's seen in simulator

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm currently learning Swift as well as XCode 6 and have been following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/74904/swift-tutorial-part-2-simple-ios-app) on creating a Tip Calculator. I believe I have followed the tutorial on point, since I have downloaded the example project file and compared it to my own and don't see any differences.

However, whenever I run the iPhone simulation on the provided example project compared to my own project, there's a striking difference in how the content is displayed on the simulator vs. the storyboard - things get cut off, don't appear, wrong location, etc.) :

-how the storyboard looks like -- [image]

I searched through Stack Overflow and have tried the following - cleaning the rebuild folder, 'resolve auto layout issues', unchecking 'auto layout', refreshed constraints in order to insure that it was running the correct files after editing. Those helped adjust the simulation to look as close as possible to storyboard, but now I am not sure what to do. I also tried changing the width to 'compact' and kept height to 'any' but still to no avail.

And it doesn't seem to be just this project, any project I create using storyboard - even as simple as dragging and dropping labels doesn't seem to correlate properly. I feel like I'm missing something stupidly fundamental, but I can't figure out what.

So my question is as an XCode newbie -
1.) What is the purpose of keeping the simulation to all 'inferred' size/orientation/etc. if it won't translate properly to any of the different simulation types? - iPhone 6 looks quites different from the iPhone 4 simulations and more. Shouldn't the iOS's point system make what I do in storyboard dynamic so as to transpose properly onto any iPhone? 
2.) Is there some specific action I should be taking to make what I see on the storyboard translate properly to the simulator?

Comment: You need to add auto layout constraints to the view. This question has been asked many times on SO and it's all because of auto layout constraints not being added.

Comment: Note, unchecking auto layout is the worst thing you can do in this case.

Comment: @abeer If you want to keep auto layout off, which is fine, but then you will have to resize and reposition your UILabels and UITextFields using code depending upon what screen size you are dealing with.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I should have clarified I am using auto layout

Comment: Ok thanks I've been messing around with autolayout constraints, I think it's quite annoying to have to do all this work, but I'm getting used to it :)